# How does the browser expose currently playing audio?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, media-player, web-audio-api

I’ve noticed that pressing Pause/Play media keys can control an audio player within Chrome, and I know that on mobile devices, you can even seek through whatever’s playing out of Safari / Chrome etc

Is there a way to programmatically seek a tab/browser’s currently playing audio? I’m wondering if there’s a w3c standard for this media key functionality and/or if theres an “extension” api to pause/play/seek or get info on what’s playing, because it seems to be exposed on mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [Media Session Standard](https://w3c.github.io/mediasession).